# Copy s3 object from one location to another via CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have an s3 object which was uploaded via CloudFront(with 'restrict access' =yes). This file not accessible without CloudFront URL. How can I directly make a copy of that s3 object without downloading and re-uploading to dest location?

Comment: you mean to say to want to directly upload to CloudFront?

Comment: as far as I know it is not possible to "upload files via cloudfront". If you want to copy an object from one s3 bucket to another, this is possible by using the S3 SDK or the REST interface.

Comment: No @Vijayanath Viswanathan I want to copy a file from one bucket to another. This file is stored using CloudFront. Therefore, I am not able to copy it.

Comment: @RohitNegi we need a better understanding of your issue: yes, you can upload objects *through* CloudFront, but they are not stored *in* CloudFront -- they are still stored in the bucket behind it.  Uploading via CloudFront should not make you be unable to copy the object, so there must be something else causing the problem.  Inspect the object in the S3 console to see who owns it and what its permissions are.

Comment: The owner is 'CloudFront Origin Access Identity XXXXXXXXXXX'